# zf2 oauth2 catching extra params

Tags: php, zend-framework2, oauth-2.0, laminas-api-tools

I'm using apigility under the zf2 framework to build my Rest server

So, we are rebuilding the rest server and our client app is calling the /oauth with extra parameters and I'm not sure how to get those parameters.

By default, /oauth will require `client_id, client_secret,` and `grant_type`. Now, my client app also is passing in `client_language` and `client_platform`. How do I intercept these variables?

I'm thinking of building on bootstrap, but I couldn't get it working...

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to mix apples and pears here.

The OAuth route is to obtain access to the api system once you have access you would set language, platform etc via an RPC service.

so:

Step 1: Get your Bearer token
Step 2: Using your bearer token, post to a secure RPC service and set language / client_platform etc.

From your RPC service you would access the variables like so:

```
$variable    = (string) $this->params()->fromRoute('language', '<enter defautl here>');
```